# Sqlite 2 and MySQL databases shared by different web apps

Tags: php, sqlite

Hi I was wondering about different PHP web apps including a Yii one sharing sqlite 2 or a MySQL database.... if they make modifications at the same time does sqlite 2 and MySQL temporarily lock the database so that a Yii and normal PHP application keep the databases working properly?

Comment: BTW to use a sqlite2 database in Yii: 'connectionString' => 'sqlite2:thedatabase.db'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do. In the same way that two different users browsing the web app, each one locks the DB.
You can figure two different Apps, as two different pages on the same App. In both cases you are working "stateless", so some microseconds the RDBMS works for one of the Apps and on other microseconds, it works for the other app, or for both (queueing until unlocked)
In the case of Sqlite, there is no engine, but anyway, the librarys, solves (and guarantees) sharing and looking